# Can I use multiple Schema.org itemscope on one page?

Tags: schema.org

I have been looking around on Schema.org but I don't understand one thing.
Can a single HTML page be made up of multiple schemas? If so do they need to be nested?

We have a one page landing / selling page we are working on.
I would like to have the following Schemas in place on it:

- Organization
- Product
- Product Reviews

I am guessing the product reviews need to be nested within a product?  Or can they be in a totally different part of the page?

Looked over what little docs there are.

Comment: Hi, Today, there is a nice [documentation](http://schema.org/docs/documents.html) about Schema.org usage.
**So plz close/remove your question.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple schemas as well as mix on other markup types.

Some schema types naturally nest other types, like a product may contain product reviews. It is possible to markup the reviews outside the product but you may find less systems pick up the association correctly.

Comment: Do you know if having an organization / product in the same page would reflect negatively from a SEO perspective.   We are building 1 page sites to sell each of our products.  The organization Schema would be useful to highlight our parent brand.

Comment: It should not. you are providing search engines with extra clues on the meaning behind your content. If those clues are correct that should only help.